# What property does soapui property window refer to? Is it the http request properties?

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, web, soapui

I'm trying to do a web service testing using SOAPUI. When I try to add the username and properties in the SOAPUI property window, I am getting the response. However, when i try to add the same username and password in the SOAP header in my request xml using  tag, I'm getting the HTTP401 unauthorized error. 
I'm trying to understand how does SOAPUI achieve this. Could anyone please navigate me through this error. Thanks.

Comment: Is this what you are talking about? http://www.soapui.org/rest-testing/understanding-rest-parameters.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the bottom of your SoapUI window, you should find an "http log". This will allow you to view EXACTLY what SoapUI is sending the your Web Service.

Typically you will not include your username or password within the XML itself, but in the http headers that come before your content (xml).

Comment: Thanks. I could find the option in SoapUI.